# When was it first confirmed that Obiwan and Anakin fought WITH clones and not AGAINST them?

Tags: star-wars, attack-of-the-clones, clones

The first reference to the Clone Wars is obviously *A New Hope*:

> General Kenobi, years ago you served my father in the Clone Wars.

However, it would be easy to assume that the Leia was referring a conflict fought *against* clones. Obviously, the canon is that the Jedi fought besides them.

My question is: When was that confirmed to be the case? The most obvious possibility is Episode II. But is there any other earlier reference? Were there viewers who thought the Republic and Jedi would be fighting *against* clones in the clone wars before the release of Episode II?

Comment: You mean earlier *published or screened* as opposed to chronological in-universe?

Comment: Yes, earliest published or screened out-of-universe.

Answer (score 5):

As you mention, some had assumed the clones were the Republic's adversary in the Clone Wars. This included Timothy Zahn while writing the Thrawn trilogy. As the author himself later explained:

> "Certainly," Thrawn said. "Created from a tissue sample, probably sometime just before the real C'baoth's death."
>
> "Early in the war, in other words," Pellaeon said, swallowing hard. The early clones—or at least those the fleet had faced¹⁵—had been highly unstable, both mentally and emotionally. Sometimes spectacularly so ... "And you deliberately brought this thing aboard my ship?" he demanded.
>
> [...]
>
> ¹⁵ Again, my assumptions about the Clone Wars were exactly backward: I assumed the clones would be fighting *against* the Republic instead of being on their side. (Nice twist, George!)
>
> Fortunately, *facing* doesn't necessarily mean *fighting*. My choice of words here was pure luck, but it helped me avoid a retroactive gaffe. <sub>—TZ</sub>
>
> <sub>*[Heir to the Empire: The 20th Anniversary Edition](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Heir_to_the_Empire:_The_20th_Anniversary_Edition)* (2011)</sub>

The same footnotes also explain that the early Expanded Universe authors were "told [by Lucasfilm] that the Clone Wars took place thirty-five years before *A New Hope*." These ideas continued into later pre-prequel works, including *The Last Command* establishing that the clone faction was called the "[Clone Masters](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Clone_Master)" (later retconned as referring to the splinter Kaminoan group that appears in the *Battlefront II* campaign mode).

However, by 1994, references to the Clone Wars had become more vague, likely to avoid contradiction with the upcoming prequel trilogy:

> ##### Clone Wars
>
> The Clone Wars was a terrible conflict that erupted during the time of the Old Republic (some thirty-five years prior to the start of *Star Wars IV: A New Hope*). The conflict produced such heroes as Bail Organa, Anakin Skywalker, and Obi-Wan Kenobi, who served as a general. Few details about the period have been revealed, but we know that the Jedi Knights and their allies battled to defend the Old Republic against its enemies. [SW, ESB, RJ]
>
> <sub>*[A Guide to the Star Wars Universe: Second Edition](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/A_Guide_to_the_Star_Wars_Universe,_Second_Edition,_Revised_and_Expanded)* (1994)</sub>

By 2000's *[The Essential Chronology](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Essential_Chronology_(real-world_book))*, the Clone Wars were referred to only as a "furious conflagration" that destroyed many historical archives, providing a rationale for why the in-universe history book doesn't have any substantial information on it.

As far as I've been able to find, the *Essential Chronology* reference is the latest description of the Clone Wars that appeared in official material before *Attack of the Clones* and its tie-in material. Even the [announcement of the film's title](http://www.cnn.com/2001/SHOWBIZ/Movies/08/07/star.wars.2/index.html) in August 2001 didn't include any new information about the Clone Wars, and prominent commentators at the time were apparently assuming the clones would be a new set of enemies for the Jedi to face:

> When the press release that said:
>
> "Harkens back to the sense of pure fun, imagination and excitement that characterized the classic movie serials and pulp space fantasy adventures that inspired the 'Star Wars' saga..."
>
> ...well, he's right. So many of us think of these chapter titles as being THE title. No, the title is STAR WARS... ATTACK OF THE CLONES is what this chapter is about. And frankly, it's a helluvalot better than non-stop robot fights. These clones aren't Dolly the sheep. These clones kill the Jedi, destroy the classic era of peace that has existed for quite some time. Clones mean blood and sadness and despair. Clones attack with no quarter, no mercy. ATTACK OF THE CLONES... Yeah, I can live with it. Why the hell not, the title makes me giggle and look forward to the film. Besides it pisses off so many, and that rules!
>
> <sub>[Ain't It Cool News post by Harry Knowles on August 7, 2001](http://legacy.aintitcool.com/node/9792)</sub>

There also wasn't any official confirmation as of March 2002, two months before *Attack of the Clones*, in a *Vanity Fair* story about the film:

> Talking to Lucas and his cast about *Episode II* is a maddening exercise in navigating the proprieties of what can and can’t be revealed, lest the intrigue be ruined for Timmy Moviegoer. Lucas admits that this is the film in which we see the start of the “Clone Wars” alluded to in the original *Star Wars*, which have something to do with the demise of the good Republic and rise of the bad Empire, but when he’s asked, “Clones of what or whom, precisely?,” he chuckles and says, “Well, *that* you’ll have to see in the movie.” (Internet speculation centers on Jango Fett, father of the cultishly popular character Boba Fett, a bounty hunter who figured in the plots of *Episodes V* and *VI*, i.e. *The Empire Strikes Back* and *Return of the Jedi*.)
>
> <sub>[Vanity Fair, "Love in a Distant Galaxy", March 2002](https://archive.vanityfair.com/article/2002/3/love-in-a-distant-galaxy)</sub>

According to Wookieepedia, the video game *[Jedi Starfighter](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Jedi_Starfighter)* (also released in March 2002) was the [first appearance](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Clone_trooper/Legends#Appearances) of clone troopers within the Legends continuity:

[image: Screenshot of Jedi Starfighter gameplay, showing a Jedi Starfighter fighting Droid Starfighters alongside Republic Gunships]

I haven't been able to find an earlier appearance, and parts of the plot of the game involve Jedi protagonists fighting alongside clone troopers at the Battle of Geonosis, so I'm inclined to say ***Jedi Starfighter*** was the first such official work.